# How to open an accordion from a hidden div

Tags: jquery, html

I can't seem to figure this out.

I'm trying to make a harmonica for a responsive website. This is what I currently got.

```
<div class="fake"></div>
<div class="panel-section" id="panel-section-services">
    <div class="panel-header">
         <h1 class="text-uppercase">Diensten</h1>
         <span class="border"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Body comes here<p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="fake"></div>
<div class="panel-section" id="panel-section-vacature">
    <div class="panel-header">
         <h1 class="text-uppercase">Vacatures</h1>
        <span class="border"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Body comes here<p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="fake"></div>
<div class="panel-section" id="panel-section-contact">
    <div class="panel-header">
         <h1 class="text-uppercase">Contacteer ons</h1>
         <span class="border"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Body comes here<p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a "fake" button is clicked (which is overlapping the "head"), the body of the current container needs to open and the rest needs to close. Just like what a normal harmonica does.

The problem is, I can't seem to access the element I need.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.panel-body').hide();  
});

$('.fake').click(function () {
     $('.panel-body').hide();  
    var header = $(this).find('.panel-header').first()   ;
    var element = $(header).next('.panel-body');

    if (element.is(':visible')) {
        element.slideUp();
    } else {
        $('.panel-body').slideUp()(element.slideDown());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hchpus01/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You are getting your elements in the wrong way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.panel-body').hide();  
});

$('div.fake').click(function () {
 var element = $(this).next().find('.panel-body');
 if (element.is(':visible')) {
    element.slideUp();
 } 
 else 
 {
    $('.panel-body').slideUp();
    element.slideDown();
 }
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/hchpus01/3/

Comment: That actually did the trick, thanks! I guess I didn't need that header to get my element.